# IIS: Acesso a directoria remota

Tags: windows, iis, dotnet-cli

Tenho uma aplicação .NET instalada no IIS 8 de determinado server (imaginemos 100.1.1.1). Utilizei o utilizador admin (o administrador). No entanto não consigo ter acesso a uma directoria (e ficheiros) remota (imaginemos 100.1.1.9).

No entanto quando faço login no server como admin tenho acesso a esta directoria e ficheiros pelo Explorer. Também tenho acesso a esta directoria/ficheiros através de uma aplicação de consola (dotnet) que corre no Task Scheduler (tarefa colocada pelo utilizador admin).

O que é que poderá ser? Pode ser um problema de domínios?

Como posso verificar se o IIS 8 (server) e a minha app MYAPP tem acesso àquela directoria/ficheiros remotos?

O IIS 8 corre num server `Windows Server 2012 R2` e a instalação do IIS 8 é básica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

já enfrentei algo semelhante e meu problema era permissão de acesso ao diretório remoto, faça o seguinte, entre nas configurações avançadas do "ApplicationPool" que sua aplicação está usando no IIS e lá configure uma identidade (usuário/senha) que tenha acesso a esse diretório remoto, acredito que isso resolverá seu problema.

[Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/troubleshoot/iis/understanding-identities) tem informações de como funciona essa questão de permissão

E [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) como fazer essa mudança no IIS.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).